# How to measure self resonance frequency of coil using CRO?

Tags: oscilloscope, coil, frequency-measurement

I have antenna coil for tuning an antenna. I want to measure self resonant frequency of the antenna coil.

Can anyone tell me how to measure it with an oscilloscope? What will be the experimental setup?

Comment: This is better suited for a network analyzer (or general-purpose spectrum analyzer), as you'd sweep a range of frequencies and look for the point where the phase response hits zero / the impedance peaks. A scope isn't necessarily the best tool for this.

Comment: I don't have Network analyzer..please tell me oscilloscope method for obtaining self resonance frequency of coil.

Comment: Do you habe a little more information? Do you have a signal generator to generate sine waves with different frequencies?

Comment: is there any tank cap. connected across the coil?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a signal generator, you can setup a circuit with known capacitance and sweep the frequency.  If you put one channel on one side of the cap and the other channel on the other side, when the signals of the two sides are of the cap are 90 degrees out of phase and that is your resonance.  Either that or look for peak gain across the cap.